# Formal semantics (Montague, type-theoretical) of noun clauses

Tags: semantics, nouns, formal-semantics, subordination, montague-grammar

Partee has nice summary about the formal semantics of relative clause http://people.umass.edu/partee/MGU_2005/MGU05Lec10.pdf (subordinate adjectival clause). E.g. 
`At least one boy who Mary loves is happy` 
has semantics 
`∃x (boy(x) & loves(x)(Mary) & happy(x))`

Is there similar formal semantics of noun clauses, e.g. formal semantics of the sentence `He told me that the match had been cancelled`?

Noun clauses are the most mysterious clauses (from 3 types of clauses - noun, relative and adverbial), because there is no book about them (there are lot of books about adverbial clauses, although - none of them is about formal semantics) and no chapter in Sementics books (e.g. https://www.degruyter.com/viewbooktoc/product/175240 has chapter about adverbial clauses but no chapter about noun clauses, although Chapter 68 `Copular Clauses` contain some examples that seems to be noun clauses).

Maybe noun clauses is more widely known under different name that is used in linguistics?

E.g. `John took an object` can be represented by `take_past(John, object)`, but how can we represent `John said that the book was good`? `say_past(John, full_sentence)`? Is it possible the replace object/Noun in function `say_past` with the full sentence? What kind of logical expression we get in this case?

Comment: Noun clauses in traditional grammar are called content clauses in modern grammar.

Comment: But not everybody speaks Modern Grammar all the time; in fact, every linguist has their own set of terminology, and can probably deliver an impromptu 50-minute lecture on why each one is chosen and how they use it.